# what is the complexity of this algorithm , can i sum it to infinity?

Tags: algorithm, loops, while-loop, time-complexity, logarithm

```
Func(n)
{
   i = n
   while(i>=1)
      g(i);
      i = i/3;
}
```

what is the complexity of this algorithm?
(while the complexity of g(n) is theta(n²))
I assumed for bigger n's you say that the complexity is

n² + (n/3)² + (n/3²)² + (n/3³)²..... to infinity.

And the answer is theta(n²).
Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at the series that we have got in our hands.

```
=> n² + (n²/3) + (n/3)² + (n/3²)² + (n/3³)²..... 
taking n² common
=> n² * [ 1 + (1/3) + (1/3)² + (1/3²)² + (1/3³)²..... ]
```

As `[ 1 + (1/3) + (1/3)² + (1/3²)² + (1/3³)²..... ]` is a decreasing series, it is equal to `1`.

Thus the answer is `O(n²)`

---

**EDIT 1:**

Prove for the sum of series `[ 1 + (1/3) + (1/3)² + (1/3²)² + (1/3³)²..... ]`, is below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! thats what i did , and my lecturer did not accept this answer. He said that the number of values in the sum is log3(n) and not infinity. can i assume its infinity?

Comment: @yair, No you cannot assume it is infinity, because there are `log3(n)` values. But what you can say is the series will sum upto `1`, or `< 2` as in this case.

Comment: A decreasing series must go to infinity , if i want to sum it , no? if not i must sum it with normal geometric equation , no?

Comment: @yair, give me a moment, I will post the proof.

Comment: @yair, the proof for the series is in the image I posted.

Comment: i cant see the picture

Comment: @yair, It is there in the answer. Can you see the edit I made to my answer?

Comment: i can see the edit , you say its below but there is nothing below.

Answer (score 3):

As you have observed, the loop runs as follows.

```
Iteration 1: n^2 = n^2/3^0
Iteration 2: (n/3)^2 = n^2/3^2
Iteration 3: (n/3^2)^2 = n^2/3^4
Iteration 4: (n/3^3)^2 = n^2/3^6
...
Iteration k: (n/3^(k-1))^2 = n^2/3^(2*(k-1))
```

Using the formula for Summation of a geometric progression, we get that total time taken is

`T(iteration1) + T(iteration2) + ... + T(Iterationk)`

```
term 1 = n^2
ratio = 1/9
sum = 9 * n^2 / 8
```

When K is a large number that can be assumed to be infinite.

Since Big O notation ignores constants,

`O( 9* n^2 /8) = O(n^2)`

Comment: Can i assume that K is infinity?

Answer (score 1):

Rigorously speaking, `i` is an integer and it soon becomes exactly `0` (after `floor(log3(n)`) iterations), so there is no reason to go to infinity.

Anyway, considering `i` as a rational results in an approximation of the true formula that doesn't change the asymptotic behavior, still O(n²). The approximation appears in two ways

- i/3 may differ from floor(i/3);
- one can add to infinity; the terms smaller than 1 just add to 4/3 at worse, which is completely neglectible.